# How to automate API testing with Java for LeanFT / Cucumber framework automation framework?

Tags: java, cucumber, leanft

How can I automate API testing with Java?
We have built a testing automation framework with the combination of LeanFt / Cucumber. We are automating our GUI-based application by using LeanFt tool and writing test scenarios with Cucumber. Now we are planning to test an API with this framework. How can a Java script help to build a process to test this API?

Comment: this is quite general question, therefore, here is some hints: if you are going to have performance/load testing as well, take a look to following powerfull tools - [gatling](https://gatling.io) , [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org) and [blazmeter](https://www.blazemeter.com). From point of view of clean API testing, try to consume Spock, Karate, RestAssured